# Source code viewer through Html page

Tags: html

Hi im demonstrating the **html** tags that are new in **CSS3** and I'm making a documentation for the easy viewing and interpretation on comparing both the source code and the output.And its its really hard for me going to the source code and then selecting the file and browsing it on the browser

It would be great if I could view both the source code and the output
on the same html page.

For example(I m talking from the page I ve attached below) if I select Source code the source code must be displayed on the screen or from any of the text editors.

I don't know whether it is possible to do so,If possible it would be great
if anyone of you could guide me.

[image: On clicking the source code link the source code must be viewed]

Comment: You mean you want what is available when typing ctrl-maj-I in most browsers ?

Comment: my link code is <a href="file:///home/gladnick/work/projects/css3/2d-matrix-method.html"><Pre>2D Transform Matrix Method Source Code</pre></a> and the source code of "file:///home/gladnick/work/projects/css3/2d-matrix-method.html" must be displayed on clicking the link

Comment: @dystroy sorry couldn't understand what is the "maj" in that ctrl-maj-I command!!

Comment: Sorry. I meant ctrl-uppercase-I. That's the shortcut to open the browser's developer tools. For example https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

Comment: Thanks!!Good idea!!But its not showing me the complete source code right?

Comment: It shows you the complete source code, with a lot of goodies (interpreted css with reasons, element displayed when you hover the mouse, search, etc.). I suggest you read [the doc](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/). Other browsers have similar tools and they're the most essential tool of any web developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the source of just one element, do this:

HTML: `<div id="one"><span id="two"></span></div>`
JS:

```
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML // returns <span id="two"></span>
document.getElementById('one').outerHTML // returns <div id="one"><span id="two"></span></div>
```

To get the source of the entire page, do this:

```
document.doctype + document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

`document.doctype` returns the doctype, and `document.documentElement.outerHTML` returns the code for the `<html>` tag and everything inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the developer tools you have in all modern browsers (the most advanced ones being Chrome and Firefox).

You typically open such a toolset using the Ctrl-Uppercase-i shortcut.

Then you have a lot of useful tools, as described [here for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/) or [here for Firefox](http://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2012/01/31/firefox-adds-powerful-new-developer-tools/).

One of them seems to be exactly what you need. For example in Chrome, the first tab, called "Elements", [shows you the source code with a lot of goodies](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) (interpreted css with reasons, element displayed when you hover the mouse, search, etc.).

I'd suggest you take the time to read the linked documentation, as this is an essential tool of any web developer. And you won't be able to stop using those tools as soon as you go deeper in javascript or css.

Comment: Editing(adding the codes,saving,etc) the source code is going to be another challenge through this developer tools right?

Comment: Yes. You must use an editor too. Note that you generally can't simply generate and see as most modern web sites aren't static : part of the content is generated by javascript so user interactions change the displayed page.